# CXF Soap WS Client stub .pfx certificate authentication

Tags: java, soap, cxf, jax-ws

SOAP Webservice is hosted as backend and authenticated using IBM Datapower Http mutual handling, i have the wsdl file and relevent schema used wsimport to generate
the java client stub code and also have the .pfx private key.

From Mozilla Firfox, if i attach the certificate in the request, i am able to access the Datapower, but not getting the response which is ok.
From SOAPUI, i was able to get the response when i use the certificates, and attach the Soap request with a custom SOAP Header.

With just using the jax-ws Http connection, i am able to get the response as a stream back when i attach the SOAP Request as an xml file.

I am trying to use Apache CXF to attach the .pfx file, i also used the system.properties to set the javax.net.ssl.keyStore attribute.

I wanted to know is there a way to attach the certificate (.pfx) in the CXF client from java. Also how to manipulate the custom header element in Soap header.

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.

PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

used

```
Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, 
                WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP + " " + 
                WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE + " " + 
                WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPT);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "myAlias");
        WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
        cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```